# Getting a domain name owned by someone else?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Buy a registered domain?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9947/buy-a-registered-domain)

I'm in the process of creating this website, but the name I wanted for the hosting seems to be taken. Namejet seems to be auctioning it, but it seems a bit too fishy for my taste. I go to the link and there's nothing there, just ads.

Can anyone recommend what the best way to get a domain owned by someone else is? My only alternative seems to be making an extremely long one nobody will remember!

Sorry for the extremely noob question, but hey, need to start somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

[GoDaddy.com](http://www.godaddy.com/default.aspx) has some great tools and services that will help in your efforts to get domains that are already taken (in the event that they are not renewed, they can attempt to be the first to grab it), and also some tools for looking for similar or variations of domain names you want.

I highly recommend them.

Comment: If you can see past the sexist ads, terrible interfaces and elephant-hunting CEO.

Comment: Yeah, I can. Distractions and annoyances (all the up-sell attempts) aside, the service itself is really top-notch.

Comment: By the way, before you buy anything (or right at checkout), be sure to google "godaddy codes" to find the latest discount codes to apply to your order. You'll save a little.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this website: [Pool.com](http://pool.com)

It's one of the best sites to snip the domains.

Godaddy also Provide the feature but I prefer [Pool.com](http://pool.com) or [Snapnames.com](https://www.snapnames.com/)

with these sites you can buy the domain if it will expire only and the process called "Snipping".

=*=

But if the Domain is for Sell:
you can find it here : [www.sedo.com](http://www.sedo.com)

Answer (score 0):

Searching a bit shows an article: [How to Buy a Domain Name Owned by Someone Else](http://www.allbusiness.com/technology/internet-domain-names/2631-1.html)
which might get you an idea. because in my opinion this is something you can only learn by experience.

From my experience buying someone else's domain can become a time consuming task.
for example you might want to make use of a transferring service like [escrow.com](http://escrow.com)

Answer (score 0):

Try any of these

1. Check the domain expiry from who.is and try to grab when it drops.(unlikely to happen)
2. Check whether same domain name available on different TLD or gTLD like .net, .co, .in, .info.
3. Put a backorder for the domain through pool.com see whether they can get you the domain.

If a domain name is on auction then he/she definitely trying to make some money out of it. You really like that domain name and think you can earn profit from it then try negotiating with the person see whether you can afford the cost. See how many people are biding, current site traffic and domain appraisal value. If you don't see lot of bidding or no bidding so far then just wait patiently he will not renew it for long time. Good Luck :)